# Jena read hook not invoked upon duplicate import read

Tags: jena

My problem will probably be explained better with code.

Consider the snippet below:

```
// First read
OntModel m1 = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
RDFDataMgr.read(m1,uri0);
m1.loadImports();

// Second read (from the same URI)
OntModel m2 = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
RDFDataMgr.read(m2,uri0);
m2.loadImports();
```

where `uri0` points to a valid RDF file describing an ontology model with `n` imports.

and the following custom ReadHook (which has been set in advance):

```
@Override
public String beforeRead(Model model, String source, OntDocumentManager odm) {
    System.out.println("BEFORE READ CALLED: " + source);
}
```

Global FileManager and OntDocumentManager are used with the following settings:

```
processImports = true;
caching = true;
```

If I run the snippet above, the model will be read from `uri0` and `beforeRead` will be invoked exactly `n` times (once for each import).
However, in the second read, `beforeRead` won't be invoked even once.

**How, and what should I reset in order for Jena to invoke beforeRead in the second read as well?**

What I have tried so far:

1. At first I thought it was due to caching being on, but turning it off or clearing it between the first and second read didn't do anything.
2. I have also tried removing all ignoredImport records from `m1`. Nothing changed.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious from the description. (1) try "m1.read" and "m2.read", not go via RDFDataMgr. (2) try without caching (3) while code is good, as nothing obvious is wrong, please provide a Complete Minimal Example (standalone code that someone else can run). Put it on a gist or pastebin if it is too large. Which version of Jena is this?

Answer (score 2):

Finally got to solve this. The problem was in `ModelFactory.createOntologyModel()`. Ultimately, this gets translated to `ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RDFS_INF,null)`.

All ontology models created with the static `OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RDFS_INF` will have their `ImportsModelMaker` and some of its other objects shared, which results in a shared state. Apparently, this state has blocked the reading hook to be invoked twice for the same imports.

This can be prevented by creating a custom, independent and non-static `OntModelSpec` instance and using it when creating an `OntModel`, for example:

```
new OntModelSpec( ModelFactory.createMemModelMaker(), new OntDocumentManager(), RDFSRuleReasonerFactory.theInstance(), ProfileRegistry.OWL_LANG );
```